# How to decide granularity when it comes to test cases?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, integration-testing, pytest

I have written a permissions middleware for a python/django API. Now the permissions depend on the combination of 4 different attributes let's call them `a b c and d`

Further c and d can be 1) Empty 2) Singular or 3) Multiple values so the combinations even increase further.

Initially I decided to write a single test case which would generate the combinations and map the expected outcome using truth tables.

```
 # Generate all possible combinations
 possible_combinations = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(possible_values)))


 for combination in possible_combinations:
            # Get expected result for this combination
            expected_result = get_expected_result(
                test_type=test_type, combination=combination, possible_values=possible_values)
```

Based on the combination value, set as 0 or 1 I decided the values of `a b c and d`

Now I am doing this as part of a new team and the team members came back with a criticism of the approach as it is not granular and doesn't follow best practices of having a test case do one thing.

My view on best practices is that they should very clearly and obviously serve a purposes and the purpose can depend on the task or team at hand. In this particular case the team members failed to suggest why writing this particular test case into granular parts would help.

Ultimately I ended up writing up to 30 test cases with 80% redundant code.

Is there any objectivity to this debate or is this a very subjective call?

Answer (score 0):

It all really depends on how you look at it. Sometimes it may make sense to test for more than one thing in a single unit test if they're too tightly coupled, but other times, it makes sense to test just one scenario.

Unit tests should be very explicit and their purpose should be clear from the name. The approach you're using will turn that test method into a sort of *blackbox* and it will be difficult to track what actually is wrong if it fails. In the case of single tests for each, you can easily understand where the bug is, if one test fails, but in your case, one would need some debugging to figure that out. These are some of the advantages of keeping them as granular as possible